# chown subfolders with current folder's owner and group

Tags: command-line, permissions, chown

In a bash script I want to recursively chown all subfolders of an arbitrary folder with the user and group owners of that given folder.

My approach is something like using `stat -c "%U %G" .`

But that returns only a pattern of `username[whitespace]groupname`

Of course I could just try different tools to replace the whitespace with a `:` but I would prefer to use a more "built-in" way if there is one, to just apply current ownership to the sub folders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`chown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/chown.1.html), like `chmod`, can use a reference:

```
chown [OPTION]... --reference=RFILE FILE...

Change the owner and/or group of each FILE to OWNER and/or GROUP.  With
--reference, change the owner and group of each FILE to those of RFILE.
```

So:

```
chown --reference=/some/folder -R /some/folder
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't actually need to parse the output to remove the whitespace - you added that in your command! You can just format it as you like (with `chown`'s colon syntax) in the first place:

```
$ stat -c "%U:%G" .
zanna:unicorns
```

So just pass that to `chown` with command substitution:

```
chown -R $(stat -c "%U:%G" .) .
```

Comment: Sometimes I am just blind for the obvious. Thank you!